# Content script not injected in mail.google.com/tasks/canvas recently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension that uses content script to make Google tasks web UI look a little better. The extension used to work fine, but it didn't work anymore starting from the recent 1~2 days.

After investigation, it seems that content script does not execute in mail.google.com domain. To verify this, I changed manifest to match all web pages:

manifest.json:

```
{ 
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Tasks",
  "short_name": "Tasks",
  "description": "Use Google Tasks in a much nicer way.",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/script.js"]
    }
  ]
```

}

js/scipt.js

```
alert('Content script is alerting.');
```

With this change, I can see chrome pop up an alert window when I visit pages like https://www.google.com/, https://stackoverflow.com and etc, but NOT https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas, OR https://mail.google.com/mail.

Is there anything on mail.google.com that prevents content script from executing? How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chrome 63 and 66. Try in another user profile or another version of the browser.

Comment: It's reproducible in a different chrome user profile as well. I can reproduce it in both Linux & Mac environments: (1) macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 + Chrome 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit); (2) Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 + Chrome 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Is it because your manifest defines `script.js` but your file is named `scipt.js`?